# Reactjs state variable does not update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to make a simple game of chess in react and am trying to do so in a function component utilizing react hooks. In order to move a peice the player must click the peice they want to move and then click the desired square to move it to. Below is a snippet of my board component:

```
const Board = () => {
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
    const [from, setFrom] = useState("");
    const [to, setTo] = useState("");
    ...

    const clickHandler = (i, j) => {
        if (!clicked) {
            setFrom('some_value');
            setClicked(true);
            ...
        } else {
            setTo('some_value');
            ...
            setClicked(false);
        }
        console.log(from + ', ' + to);
    }
    ...
```

the problem arrises from the `to` and `from` state variables not being updated when I want them to. The console output ends up looking like:

```
, 
some_value, 
some_value, some_value
```

where the to and from values are only updated on the next click event even when the `console.log()` is after the `setFrom()`/`setTo()` calls.

I am pretty sure that `useState` is not the hook I want to use here, but after trying `useRef` and `useReducer` a little and running into similar situations, I am in the dark as to what the best way would be to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The local variables are set when assigned at the start of your component's render. And React state updates are asynchronous, which means that your component will re-render a few milliseconds later with the new values.

So if you move the `console.log(from + ', ' + to);` to outside of your click handler, it will get executed on the next render and you should log out the values you expect.

```
const Board = () => {
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
    const [from, setFrom] = useState("");
    const [to, setTo] = useState("");

    const clickHandler = (i, j) => {
        if (!clicked) {
            setFrom('some_value');
            setClicked(true);
            ...
        } else {
            setTo('some_value');
            ...
            setClicked(false);
        }
    }

    // This should now log what you expect.
    console.log(from + ', ' + to);

    //...

}
```

---

> "I guess I should have outlined this in the post but in order to do calculations to verify the move, I have logic regarding the `to` and `from` variables in the else clause."

If you need the updated values that you set in your click handler, then you have the values because you just set them. You don't need to wait for state to update.

```
    const clickHandler = (i, j) => {
        const newFrom = 'some_value';
        const newTo = 'some_other_value';
        if (!clicked) {
            setFrom(newFrom);
            setClicked(true);
        } else {
            setTo(newTo);
            setClicked(false);
        }

        console.log(calculateDistance(newFrom, newTo))
    }
```

---

Or maybe you could use `useEffect` instead to trigger some code when those two variables change.

```
const Board = () => {
  //... state hooks

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(calculateDistance(from, to))
  }, [from, to])
  
  const clickHandler = //...
}
```

That will run after any render in which the state that `from` or `to` comes from is assigned a new value.

Comment: I guess I should have outlined this in the post but in order to do calculations to verify the move, I have logic regarding the to and from variables in the else clause.

Comment: You don't need any magic to do that because the values you just set are the values that you want. So you have them in your function, you just got to use them. Or perhaps you want `useEffect()`? It's hard to advise because I don't know how you are trying to use these variables. See my updated answer, which may help.

Answer (score 0):

The only proper way to catch updated state is useEffect hook as you are using functional components. The setState is async operation, it will be executed after all sync code.
The useEffect hook fires up right after the state has been changed so you can be sure that you catch the freshest state value.

```
// this will never show you updated state:
setState(value) // this line will be executed later
console.log(value) // shows the old state

// that's how you catch new state:
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(`The new state value is ${value}`)
}, [value])
```

Comment: are you referring to ```useEffect()``` ? Additionally, react hooks cannot be used in anything that is not a react component function.

Comment: sure, just misspelled in the night

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have come to after more research is using a `useEffect` hook in the body of the component to do the move validation and board updating with `to` being the only member of the dependency array.

```
const Board () => {
    ...
    useEffect(() => {...}, [to]);
    ...
}
```